# why +new Date() return the same as new Date().getTime()?

Tags: javascript, date

I was reading some source code, and find this. why +new Date() return the same as new Date().getTime()? What's the mechanism behind it?

```
var date = new Date()
+data == date.getTime() // true
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Notice that `date.valueOf()`  returns the same value as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the unary `+` operator—when used on types other than strings—will internally call `valueOf`. In the case of a date, it is functionally equivalent to `Date.prototype.getTime`, as both perform the same [abstract operation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-thistimevalue).

Comment: How is that different than what I said? ;) FWIW, `Date.prototype.valueOf` is of course only called when the value is a date object, not a value of  another type.

Comment: @FelixKling I was writing my answer at the same time. I wouldn't ponder too much on the timestamp privilege.

Answer (score 3):

[The unary `+` operator](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator) converts the operand to a number. In that process, [`date.valueOf`](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.valueof) will be called, which performs the same computation as [`date.getTime`](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.gettime).